# Dragging node from JTree and dropping onto JLabel to perform an action

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, applet, jtree

I want to implement DnD on my system by dragging a node from a JTree and dropping it onto a JLabel.

The JLabel is an Icon with certain properties about a machine, and by dragging the information from the JTree node onto the JLabel I want it to be able to send a message to a client listening on that machine.

Any help is much appreciated!

Example of label method:

```
private void makeLabel(String html, final String version) {
    // Create a button to link to the DR environment
    //JButton button = new JButton(html);
    JLabel machineLabel = new JLabel();
    machineLabel.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("text"));
    MouseListener listener = new DragMouseAdapter();
    machineLabel.addMouseListener(listener);
    machineLabel.setIcon(onlineIcon);
    machineLabel.setToolTipText("IP: " + html);
    //Add the button to the panel and make sure it appears
    machineLabel.setSize(25, 10);
    vecIcons.addElement(machineLabel);
    buttonPanel.add(machineLabel);
    buttonPanel.setVisible(true);
    buttonPanel.validate();
    dynaScrollPane.validate();
    buttonPanel.repaint();
    dynaScrollPane.repaint();
  }
```

DragMouseAdapter method:

```
    private class DragMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
  JComponent c = (JComponent) e.getSource();
  TransferHandler handler = c.getTransferHandler();
  handler.exportAsDrag(c, e, TransferHandler.LINK);
  }
}
```

Then in order to make my tree draggable I just have:

```
exampleTree.setDragEnabled(true);
```

Comment: May be this can help you: [Drag and Drop and Data Transfer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html) and [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DnDdraganddropJTreecode.htm).

Comment: I believe this is covered by the regular [Java DnD support](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html).

Comment: I did try the code provided by following the Java tutorial but it didn't really work with jLabels, instead of dropping onto the label it put the control string next to the label.

Comment: That sounds more like a problem with Swing rendering than a problem with DnD. Could you post an [scce](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: I just posted all of the related methods and code in my original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure I understand your setup: assuming you want the label to be a drop target, simply implement a custom Transferhandler which accepts the dataflavour as exported by the tree and do something with it

**EDIT**

To get hold of the TreePath use a custom Transferhandler on the tree as well: override its createTransferable which returns the TreePath:

```
    final DataFlavor flavor =new DataFlavor(TreePath.class, "treePath");
    TransferHandler treeHandler = new TransferHandler() {
        DataFlavor[] pathFlavour = new DataFlavor[] 
                  {flavor};

        /** 
         * @inherited <p>
         */
        @Override
        protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
            JTree tree = (JTree) c;
            final TreePath path = tree.getSelectionPath();
            Transferable transferable = new Transferable() {

                @Override
                public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
                    return pathFlavour;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
                    return pathFlavour[0].equals(flavor);
                }

                @Override
                public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor)
                        throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
                    return path;
                }

            };
            return transferable;
        }

        public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
            return COPY;
        }

    };
    tree.setTransferHandler(treeHandler);
    JLabel labelTarget = new JLabel("I'm a drop target!");
    TransferHandler labelHandler = new TransferHandler() {

        /** 
         * @inherited <p>
         */
        @Override
        public boolean importData(JComponent comp, Transferable t) {
            try {
                LOG.info("import from: " +  t.getTransferData(flavor));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }

        /** 
         * @inherited <p>
         */
        @Override
        public boolean canImport(JComponent comp,
                DataFlavor[] transferFlavors) {
            return true;
        }

    };
    labelTarget.setTransferHandler(labelHandler);
```

no need for an additional mouseListener

Comment: True; as I recall, _all_ the relevant mouse events are handled by java.awt.dnd.

Comment: That works well, although I need to be able to find out the exact location that the drop came from. So for example if I've got a tree with a root node of "Server1", then another node under that called "Example", which has a value in it called "Example Val", how can I get it to display something like "Drag came from Server1->Example->Example Val"? I can't find a way to do this with DataFlavours.